# Write the outcome of a for loop in multiple files in a single file in shell

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, command-substitution

I am new to shell scripting (bash/awk...etc) so please excuse me for my stupid question.
I am aware that to many of you this is so easy

I have multiple files that look like this:

```
file1.bam, ...., file1000.bam
```

and for each one of the files I am writing in terminal the following commands
and I take a number as an outcome

```
samtools view -c -F 4 file1.bam 
9
# and 
samtools view -c -f 4 file1.bam 
2
```

Now, I am fighting hard to put the outcome of all for loops in one text file
that looks like this

```
file1         9      2
...        ...      ...
file1000    100     50
```

so far I have written

```
for each in .bam
do
 echo ${each}
 samtools view -c -F 4 ${each}.bam 
 samtools view -c -f 4 ${each}.bam 
done
```

**Edit:**
output of

```
samtools view -c -F 4 file1.bam | hexdump -C

00000000  39 0a                                             |9.|
00000002
```

Comment: Please add output of `samtools view -c -F 4 file1.bam | hexdump -C` to your question.

Comment: You can redirect the entire loop at a go. Put `>file` after the `done`, and everything from all iterations goes into `file`.

Comment: @LDT, ...if we don't know what `samtools view` output looks like, how are we supposed to build or test a command to massage it into the format you want? If you write your question in a way that means only people who know `samtools` can answer it, you're severely restricting the quality of the answers you can get.

Comment: BTW, I think you want `in *.bam`, not in `.bam`; and since `each` will already contain the `.bam` suffix, you don't need `${each}.bam` in that case; you can just use `"$each"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest with `bash`:

```
for each in *.bam; do
  data1=$(samtools view -c -F 4 "${each}")
  data2=$(samtools view -c -f 4 "${each}")
  echo -e "${each}\t${data1}\t${data2}"
done
```

Comment: The only change I would make this would be to use `printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$each" "$data1" "$data2"` instead of the `echo`, since `echo`'s behavior is not reliable (in some versions and configurations `-e` needs to be used to make `\t` become a tab; in other cases `echo -e` prints the string `-e` on output).

Comment: sorry for the flub Cyrus, but how can I write the output of the loop in a txt file?

Comment: @LDT: Redirect stdout to a file: replace `done` with `done > your_text_file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing the collection and production of the final output outside of the loop:

```
for each in *.bam; do
    printf '%s\n' "${each%.*}"
    samtools view -c -F 4 "$each"
    samtools view -c -f 4 "$each"
done |
awk -v OFS='\t' '{a[NR%3]=$0} NR%3==0{print a[1], a[2], a[0]}'
```

Comment: It was works like a charm Ed. To add the output in a txt file i added in the last line 
 > "sum_bams_2.txt". 
Its impressive how nicely it works, thank you for your time